# MvvmCross Xamarin.Forms Modal Dialogs

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, modal-dialog, mvvmcross

I'm just trying to make my first app with MvvmCross but I already encounter a problem for my app and can't find anything on the web for that. I want to open a specific page as a modal dialog on supported devices (eg. iPads). For my non MvvmCross applications I do this with Rg.Plugin.Popup but I do not want it this way this time. I found a few solutions on how it can be done with native and MvvmCross but nothing about how it is done with Xamarin.Forms in combination to MvvmCross. Did I need to implement a own presenter and filter on the type of my page (because this page should always be modal on supported devices)? And if I do so, is there any example for this?

Answer (score 3):

Using MvvmCross 5.2.0, the following worked for me (on iOS at least; haven't tested on Android):

```
var bundle = new MvxBundle(new Dictionary<string, string>{ { MvxFormsPagePresenter.ModalPresentationParameter, "true" } });
await _navService.Navigate<MyViewModel>(bundle);
```

This uses the stock-standard `MvxFormsPagePresenter`, so you don't have to create your own presenter.

Comment: It does not work for the ShowViewModel method (it could take a IMvxBundle too). What kind of type is your "_navService"?

Comment: Okey got it to "work". Now I got a full screen modal dialog that is not closable. Is this normal?

Comment: You need to add the functionality to dismiss the view; I usually add a `GestureRecognizer` to the view that closes the view on tap.

Comment: How can I display a native Xamarin.Forms page (just a `ContentPage`, no ViewModels) using MvvmCross' `Navigate` function? I can't use native `Navigation.PushModalAsync` because it gives me a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I suspect a stupid question but Im using MvvmCross 7.1.2 and MvxFormsPagePresenter.ModalPresentationParameter causes errors 'MvxFormsPagePresenter' does not contain a definition for 'ModalPresentationParameter'

Answer (score 2):

I'm using MVVMCross 7.1.2 here, this was tested on Android only.

In your Views code behind implement `IMvxOverridePresentationAttribute` with code similar to this.

```
public MvxBasePresentationAttribute PresentationAttribute(MvxViewModelRequest request)
{
    if (request.PresentationValues == null) return null;

    if (request.PresentationValues.ContainsKey("NavigationMode") &&
        request.PresentationValues["NavigationMode"] == "Modal")
    {
        return new MvxModalPresentationAttribute
        {
            WrapInNavigationPage = true,
            Animated = false,
            NoHistory = true
        };
    }

    return null;
}
```

All you need to do now, is when Navigating to the view model is just pass a key value pair as the parameter like this

```
await NavigationService.Navigate<MainViewModel>(new MvxBundle(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "NavigationMode", "Modal" } }));
```

That's it... easy as that !