# Is MvvmCross 6 (with Xamarin.Forms) viewmodel-first navigation to a custom xaml-based dialog popup possible?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, modal-dialog, mvvmcross

Is there a way to use MvvmCross.Forms to do ViewModel-First Navigation to custom XAML-based dialogs?  I tried using the MvxFormsModalPresentationAttribute on a XAML class inheriting from MvxContentView but either I wasn't doing it right or that wasn't the proper way to achieve what I want.  I cannot really find any documentation for MvvmCross.Forms presentation or anything about custom XAML popups/dialogs with MvvmCross.Forms.  I'm using MvvmCross 6.0.0-beta5.

My question is possibly a duplicate of this question ([MvvmCross Xamarin.Forms Modal Dialogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45271184/mvvmcross-xamarin-forms-modal-dialogs)) but from what I can tell from looking at the MvvmCross source code the  method has changed to PresentationAttributes at some point between 5.2.0 (when that was answered) and 6.0.0-beta3.

Like the user who asked that question, for my non MvvmCross applications I do this with Rg.Plugin.Popup but I do not want it that way this time because I would like to be able to take advantage of MvvmCross and use its ViewModel-first navigation and ViewModel initialization and lifecycle hooks from inheriting MvxViewModel for my dialog's View Model.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest few thing

1. Use a stable version of the library (latest is 5.6.3), as the beta might be somehow broken and for whatever reason your attempt might not work
2. Unfortunately, you're right about the documentation, which is not very clear or there's none at all. What I would do, is to download MvvmCross sources from github ([MvvmCross github](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross) - use master branch) and check out the TestProjects -> Playground projects - this is where you can check how things should work. Just run one of the projects in there (e.g. Playground.Forms.Droid). Once you get the sources (or you can look it up online - [MvvmCross Playground Pages](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/master/TestProjects/Playground/Playground.Forms.UI/Pages)), I would suggest looking at the playground pages and how they being attributed
3. You could use different framework like [Prism](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism)

Generally speaking you should use `[MvxModalPresentation]` attribute. You can see how they use it in the [Playground project](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/master/TestProjects/Playground/Playground.Forms.UI/Pages/ModalPage.xaml.cs)

Hope that helps a bit at least